# Limit of ratio of quadratic forms

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, quadratic-forms

> **Let $Q_A,Q_B : \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be quadratic forms. Find a necessary and sufficient condition for $\lim_{\vec x
> \rightarrow \vec 0} \frac{Q_A(\vec x)}{Q_B(\vec x)}$ to exist in the
>   strong sense.**

I'm not really sure where to begin here. I wrote
$\lim_{\vec x \rightarrow \vec 0} \frac{Q_A(\vec x)}{Q_B(\vec x)} = \lim_{\vec x \rightarrow \vec 0} \frac{\sum a_{ij}x_ix_j}{\sum b_{ij}x_ix_j}$, but I'm not sure how that helps.

Since we have $\vec x \rightarrow \vec 0$, we also have $x_i \rightarrow 0$. Can we find this condition component-wise?

Comment: There are many ways for a vector to tend to $\overrightarrow{0}$. E.g. $$X^1=(x_1, 0, 0,...,0)$$
$$X^2=(0, x_2, 0,...,0)$$
$$X^3=(0, 0, x_3,...,0)$$
$$...$$
$$X^n=(0, 0, 0,...,x_n)$$
will yield different limits, assuming $b_{ii}\neq 0$ and $\frac{a_{ii}}{b_{ii}}\neq \frac{a_{jj}}{b_{jj}}$.

Comment: @rtybase So it's a necessary condition that $b_{ii}\neq 0$ and $a_{ii}/b_{ii} = a_{jj}/b_{jj}$, right?

Comment: Not yet ... other valid examples are: 
$$X^{12}=(x_1,x_2,0,...,0 )$$
$$X^{23}=(0,x_2,x_3,...,0 )$$
$$...$$